# How to use CryptoJs in the Javascript

Tags: javascript, blazor, cryptojs

I installed crypto-js like so in my Blazor project

PM> npm install crypto-js

then in the index.html, I used it like so

```
<script>
    
    ... OTHER FUNCTIONS

    function encryptMessage(message, key) {
        const keyOffSet = 10;
        const data = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(message);
        const keyLength = 24
        
    }
</script>
```

How come that I get an error of

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: CryptoJS is not defined
ReferenceError: CryptoJS is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import CryptoJS by adding CryptoJS CDN. Add the following code before your `script` tag which contains the logic.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js" integrity="sha512-E8QSvWZ0eCLGk4km3hxSsNmGWbLtSCSUcewDQPQWZF6pEU8GlT8a5fF32wOl1i8ftdMhssTrF/OhyGWwonTcXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

*Note: If you still get error, check details of the `GET` request performed in Dev Tool's Network tab, it would probably have to do with CORS or some other network policy.*

Comment: This is actually correct. How do i use this in offline mode?

Comment: @lbanez, if you want to use offline. You can access: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.1.1/crypto-js.min.js Copy content and paste to your local file

Comment: @Hungnn is correct you could copy content but I think that is not recommended due to affects on performance, though this is a small ~50kb package.  Also accepting this answer will mark this question as answered for the rest of the community